# Add confirm prompt in another language

Tags: javascript, node.js, botframework, chatbot

How to add the confirm Prompt and Good bye message in another language based on user choice of language. Lets say I want to add a spanish version thats says goodbye

```
 .cancelAction(
    "cancelRequest", "Thank you for reaching out, Good bye!",
    {
        matches: /^nevermind$|^cancel$|^cancel.*request/i,
        confirmPrompt: "This will cancel your request. Are you sure?"
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a variable which value is set depending on the language. This variable can then be used to get the corresponding text from an object.

For example:

```js
var language = "spanish";
 
var cancelTextFromLang = {
 spanish: "Gracias por comunicarte, ¡Adiós!",
 english: "Thank you for reaching out, Good bye!",
 french: "Merci d'avoir tendu la main, au revoir!"
};

console.log(cancelTextFromLang[language])
```

You can apply this to your given code like so:

```
var language = "spanish";

var cancelTextFromLang = {
    spanish: "Gracias por comunicarte, ¡Adiós!",
    english: "Thank you for reaching out, Good bye!",
    french: "Merci d'avoir tendu la main, au revoir!"
};

.cancelAction(
    "cancelRequest", cancelTextFromLang[language],
    {
        matches: /^nevermind$|^cancel$|^cancel.*request/i,
        confirmPrompt: "This will cancel your request. Are you sure?"
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Im using session.userData.languagePreference and Im thinking to add an if statement inside the cancelAction but the syntax is wrong, I cant put the if statement there :/

```
.cancelAction(
    if ( session.userData.languagePreference = 0;) {

  "cancelRequest", "Thank you for reaching out, Good bye!",
  {
      matches: /^nevermind$|^cancel$|^cancel.*request/i,
      confirmPrompt: "This will cancel your request. Are you sure?"
  }
);
```

Answer (score -1):

The Bot Framework supports localization. You can read about how to do this in Node [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-localization?view=azure-bot-service-3.0). This page will explain how to determine the language for the bot user either via prompting the user or automatically. it also describes how to add the language strings for your prompts.

They key to bot localization is the session.preferredLocal() method. This method saves and gets the user specific locale preference.

The easiest method to determine the language locale and set it is to prompt the user. Here's a Node example

```
bot.dialog('/localePicker', [
function (session) {
    // Prompt the user to select their preferred locale
    builder.Prompts.choice(session, "What's your preferred language?", 'English|Español');
},
function (session, results) {
    // Update preferred locale
    var locale;
    switch (results.response.entity) {
        case 'English':
            locale = 'en';
            break;
        case 'Español':
            locale = 'es';
            break;            
    }
    session.preferredLocale(locale, function (err) {
        if (!err) {
            // Locale files loaded
            session.endDialog(`Your preferred language is now ${results.response.entity}`);
        } else {
            // Problem loading the selected locale
            session.error(err);
        }
    });
}
```

]);

The first part of this code prompts the user for their preferred language and gives them English and Spanish as the two option available. Based on the user response, the locale code is then set by calling session.preferredLocale().

In order to make use of the user's preferred locale, you will need a corresponding localization prompt file. These files will contain the various bot prompts in the corresponding language. You will need one file per language you intend on supporting.

Normally, these files will be in ./locale/{language}/index.json where {language} is the language code, (ex 'en' or'es'). The files are json and will look like this:
for English

```
{
    "greeting": ["Hello!", "Hi there"]
}
```

and for Spanish

```
{
    "greeting": ["Hola!", "Hola"]
}
```

Here is an example of how you code would look

```
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, [
function (session) {
    session.send("greeting");
    session.beginDialog('/localePicker');
},
function (session) {
    builder.Prompts.text(session, "text_prompt");
}
]);
```

Behind the scenes, what's basically happening,the index.json file returned by session.preferredLocale() is searched for the prompt, if it finds one, it returns that otherwise it will return the prompt set for the default locale.